# Usar Clausura where quando classe é dinâmica

Tags: c#, .net

Tenho uma classe base:

```
public class MinhaClasse<T> : Controller where T : class
{
    public List<T> BuscarVarios(string nome)
    {
        return db.Set<T>().Where(/*?????*/);
    }
}
```

Como faço pra usar a clausura `Where` quando minha classe é dinâmica?

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua dúvida está muito vaga. Por favor, clique em [edit] e coloque mais detalhes para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: É verdade @jbueno .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embora eu não consiga ver um motivo para fazer isso. O máximo que eu consigo pensar nesse momento para resolver esse problema é pedir uma `Func<T, bool>` ao invés de uma `string`.

Veja na prática

```
public class MinhaClasse<T> : Controller where T : class
{
    public List<T> BuscarVarios(Func<T, bool> filtro)
    {
        return db.Set<T>().Where(filtro).ToList();
    }
}
```

Na hora de usar você faria

```
minhaClassePersonalizada.BuscarVarios(x => x.Nome == "Joaquim");
```